# Windows 7: how to remove write protection for my SD memory card?

Tags: windows-7, sd-card, write-protect

I am not able to write anything to my SD memory card, using Windows 7.

How can I remove the write protection?

Comment: First, make sure you follow @oKtosiTe's suggestion, and then try the following... I once had this issue...It turns out, *I had enabled ["ReadyBoost"](http://www.microsoft.com/india/windows/windows-vista/features/readyboost.aspx) on the drive*, and it prevents one from writing anything to the space being used by ReadyBoost, even if the feature is turned off... To disable, click `Computer` -> Right-click the SD card and select `Properties` -> Go to the `ReadyBoost` tab -> and make sure that `Do not use this device.` is slected and that the space to reserve for system speed is at zero (0). ![alt

Comment: I assume you tried flipping the little switch on the side of the card itself?

Comment: I’ve read that some card-readers are a little wonky and that setting the switch to the allow-write position won’t work, but setting it to the *middle* does.

Answer (score 1):

Based in the detail of the OP. you should do this:

[image]

1. Put your SD in same position as Image shows
2. in the left border is a slide button.
3. Slide it UP.

There is the Write protection Disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Some programs will indicate 'write protected' but that may not always be what's really happening

It can be a hardware problem after all!

So if you are seeing problems and all other tips have exhausted, try another PC or laptop!

Worked for me: controller failures turned up in the windows event viewer (System category). Even with a hex editor separate blocks were writing okay, but writing large chunks would fail at random positions on the card.